# Changing values of the dataframe columns based on a list of indices

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 4 columns:

```
myData<-mtcars[1:20,1:4]
```

also a list with the same column names:

```
myList<-list(mpg=c(1,2,3), cyl=c(2,10), disp=integer(0), hp=c(3))
```

How can I change the values of each column of the dataframe based on the corresponding vector of a list?

So I want to set the first, second and third row of the `myData$mpg`, the second and tenth row of `myData$cyl` and so forth, to e.g. NA.

I have tried the following line but it doesn't work.

```
mapply(function(x, y)y[x, names(x)]<-NA, myList, myData, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

> Error in y[x, names(x)] : incorrect number of dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution I can think of is as follows:

```
sapply(names(myList), function(x) {myData[myList[[x]], x] <<- NA})
```

I have not used `mapply`, but your problem may be the 'global' assignment.

Providing output as:

```
myData
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp
Mazda RX4             NA   6 160.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag         NA  NA 160.0 110
Datsun 710            NA   4 108.0  NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95
Merc 280            19.2  NA 167.6 123
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65
```

Comment: Thank you Gopala! As you may have noticed, I am new in R and didn’t know about global assignment! But I think the problem with my code is likely because myData and myList have different dimensions. Thank you again.

Comment: That should not matter. Not sure. If you modify something inside a function, that is then not available outside of that function. So, you either need to 'return' what you modified from the function, or do a global assignment so that it is modified in the global environment. Ether way works.

Comment: There's no need for global assignment, just assign the results of `Map/mapply/sapply/lapply` back to the original result - `myData[] <- Map(replace, myData, myList, NA)` as I commented below. Using `<<-` is generally discouraged as it can give unintended results depending on where it ends up nested.

Comment: Agree. I like your `Map` solution a lot. Have not used it before. I don't really need to use global assignment operator, if I return a vector of full column values and assign to the data frame.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `mapply` in this way. If you don't need the row.names of the result:

```
mapply(function(data, index) {data[index] <- NA; data}, myData, myList)
```

should suffice. Otherwise, you can manually assign the row.names back.

```
`row.names<-`(mapply(function(data, index) {data[index] <- NA; data}, myData, myList), 
              rownames(myData))
                     mpg cyl  disp  hp
Mazda RX4             NA   6 160.0 110
Mazda RX4 Wag         NA  NA 160.0 110
Datsun 710            NA   4 108.0  NA
Hornet 4 Drive      21.4   6 258.0 110
Hornet Sportabout   18.7   8 360.0 175
Valiant             18.1   6 225.0 105
Duster 360          14.3   8 360.0 245
Merc 240D           24.4   4 146.7  62
Merc 230            22.8   4 140.8  95
Merc 280            19.2  NA 167.6 123
Merc 280C           17.8   6 167.6 123
Merc 450SE          16.4   8 275.8 180
Merc 450SL          17.3   8 275.8 180
Merc 450SLC         15.2   8 275.8 180
Cadillac Fleetwood  10.4   8 472.0 205
Lincoln Continental 10.4   8 460.0 215
Chrysler Imperial   14.7   8 440.0 230
Fiat 128            32.4   4  78.7  66
Honda Civic         30.4   4  75.7  52
Toyota Corolla      33.9   4  71.1  65
```

Comment: `myData[] <- Map(replace, myData, myList, NA)` for short.

Comment: That's a crazily short answer. @thelatemail

Comment: It's identical logic to your answer, which I think is the preferred way to go. `replace` is exactly `x[index] <- values; x` - so it's running the same code, just preventing a bit of typing :-)

Answer (score 2):

Another option by looping over the sequence

```
myData[] <- lapply(seq_along(myList), function(i) {
      myData[i][myList[[i]],] <- NA
      myData[[i]]})
head(myData)
#                   mpg cyl disp  hp
#Mazda RX4           NA   6  160 110 
#Mazda RX4 Wag       NA  NA  160 110
#Datsun 710          NA   4  108  NA
#Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110
#Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175
#Valiant           18.1   6  225 105
```

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was just saying in the comment below to my answer about global assignment. I could have re-written code this way instead.